# Check whether network has any isolated cliques

Tags: r, igraph

I am looking for a way to check whether a network has any isolated collection of nodes.
I mean whether there are any disconnected parts in the network.
Is there a general method for this?

Here's an example graph:

```
library(igraph)
a<-erdos.renyi.game(100,0.1)
```

I could not find any built in functions for igraph that would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
a<-erdos.renyi.game(20,0.1)
plot(a)
V(a)[degree(a) == 0]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Sorry I was not clear. I'm looking for a method that can tell me whether there are any disconnected parts in the network. (i.e. small clusters that are isolated from the rest of the network)

Comment: You mean like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730624/how-to-split-an-igraph-into-connected-subgraphs#answer-29736888 ?